# EDITED: lwc spinner not showing up for cached records

Tags: lightning-web-components, tab, spinner

**Background**: I have a lightning-tabset with two tabs, each tab contains a datatable with a filter dropdown.

Each time a tab is clicked, it calls a wire function to fetch the records for the related datatable, the controller method is annotated with `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)`.

**Issue**: When my component loads, the first time I switch from tab A to tab B I see the spinner while the records are being loaded.
But when I switch back to tab A the spinner doesn't show up anymore, switching back and forth doesn't trigger it anymore.

Another example, If I change the filter on tab A, it loads the spinner (every filter triggers a wire function) and so on for every other filter, the spinner is showing as expected.
But when I select the same filters that were chosen before, the spinner isn't showing up.

**Edit:**

Removed playground, adding my code below.

```
<template>
  <template if:true={isLoading}>
    <div class="exampleHolder">
      <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium" variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
    </div>
  </template>
  <lightning-tabset>
    <lightning-tab label="Tab 1" onactive={handleTabChange} value="1">
      <template if:false={isLoading}>
        <lightning-datatable
          key-field="id"
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          show-row-number-column
          class="slds-max-medium-table_stacked">
        </lightning-datatable>
            </template> 
    </lightning-tab>
    <lightning-tab label="Tab 2" onactive={handleTabChange} value="2">
      <template if:false={isLoading}>
        <lightning-datatable
          key-field="id"
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          show-row-number-column
          class="slds-max-medium-table_stacked">
        </lightning-datatable>
            </template> 
    </lightning-tab>
</lightning-tabset>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import getData from '@salesforce/apex/getAsyncController.getData';

    isLoading = true;
    data = [];
    program = null;
    filter = null;
@wire(getData)
    wiredMethod({error, data}){  
        getData({program:this.program,filter:this.filter})
        .then(data => {
            this.data = data
            this.error = null;
            this.isLoading = false:
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.data = null;
            this.error = error;
        });

    }   


handleTabChange(event) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.activetabContent = event.target.value;
    this.callAsync();
}
callAsync() {
    getData({program: this.program,filter: this.filter})
        .then(data => {
            this.data = data
            this.error = null;
            this.isLoading = false:
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.data = null;
            this.error = error;
        });
}
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class getAsyncController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List < Program__c > getData(String program, String filter) {
        if (filter == null)
            return [SELECT Id FROM Program__c WHERE Name =: program];
        else
            return [SELECT Id FROM Program__C WHERE Name =: program AND Status__c =: filter]
    }
}
```

Is there another way to make the spinner show up? Setting IsLoading to true/false works when I get data from the server but not for cached records it seems.

Comment: Not sure the playground is showing your issue. If I change the setTimeout to 100ms, the issue goes away. Can you post your actual handleTabChange method? Mostly likely your wire adaptor is never getting called because of the cache. Are the arguments the same each time you make the call?

Comment: Please add at lease the declaration part of the `getSomething` method.

Comment: @PhilW, I modified my question, remove playground and added actual code.

Comment: @digglemister you're right, changing the setTimeout to 100ms works for the playground but doesn't work for my actual code, I updated my questions

Comment: Please add the declaration of the `getData` function.

Comment: @Json Wait, you said you're using a wire function, but your edits don't show any use of `@wire`. Does `this.program` change between calls to `getData`?

Comment: Updated code snippet @PhilW

Comment: @digglemister sometime it changes, sometimes it stays the same. for instance when if I only change the filter then the program stays the same

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood me. Can you show the client-side definition of getData.

Comment: @PhilW added the definition.

Comment: This is very weird code. Wires are intended to be invoked automatically by the LWC infrastructure based on reactive parameter changes. If you want to invoke Apex explicitly you should use imperative Apex. As already said, wires cache data so no call is made to the server If the data has already been fetched (for specific parameter values) and is still "valid". To guarantee a call, use imperative to a non-cacheable aura enabled method.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW for your feedback. I will refactor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the `@wire` method - you are using an imperative call, so just do that.

Second, since the data is now cached, it's probably returning so quickly that the spinner is not getting time to actually show. If you REALLY want it to show you could add a wee timeout for effect.

```
connectedCallback(){
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.callAsync();
}

handleTabChange(event) {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.activetabContent = event.target.value;
  //add a small delay so the spinner shows
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    this.callAsync();
  }, 1500);
  
}
callAsync() {
  getData({program: this.program,filter: this.filter})
    .then(data => {
       this.data = data
       this.error = null;
       this.isLoading = false:
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.data = null;
      this.error = error;
    });
}
```